# How to determine if a cluster is at its maxZoom level?

Tags: leaflet, clustering

I'm using the [Leaflet MarkerCluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin, and I want to know whether a particular cluster represents points at the same location, or whether the cluster would break into smaller components if I zoomed in.

By default, the cluster will "spiderfy" if it represents multiple points at the same location - I'd like to detect this scenario and handle the individual points myself, rather than spiderfying (using `spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false`).

[image: pretty, but pretty useless too]

There is an event fired when you click on a cluster icon. From the documentation:

`markers.on('clusterclick', function (a) {
    // a.layer is actually a cluster
    console.log('cluster ' + a.layer.getAllChildMarkers().length);
});`

Is it possible to determine whether the cluster is at its maximum zoom level after the user has clicked on it? That is, if the user clicked on it again, would it continue to zoom in further, or does it represent points at the same location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an easier method to determine this. If the layer has associated markers, it's at its maximum zoom level (this presumably is how the spiderfy function is able to display the individual markers).

So you can simply test for the presence of markers when the user clicks:

`layer.on("clusterclick", function(a){
    if (a.layer._markers.length > 0) {
        console.log("layer at max zoom");
    } else {
        console.log("layer not at max zoom");
    }
});`

Comment: Unfortunately, this may work for your particular situation, but does not in the general case: https://plnkr.co/edit/QgWlBupvtdpl2SE0uBEo?p=preview `a.layer._markers` contains the markers that get out of the cluster on the immediately higher zoom level, i.e. if you zoom in 1 extra level. But you can still have other child markers forming a cluster, hence the clicked cluster would not have spiderfied.

Comment: FWIW I have proposed a solution there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669565/leaflet-markercluster-how-to-check-if-cluster-is-going-to-be-spiderfied-i-e/49854790#49854790

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just did a quick test and was able to confirm that the `animationend` event will do the trick:

```
// markers is the markerClusterGroup
markers.on('animationend', function(a){
  console.log('animationend zoom level: ', map.getZoom())
})

markers.on('clusterclick', function(a){
  console.log('clusterclick zoom level: ', map.getZoom())
})
```

And the console confirmed it:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the tip. But I discovered an even easier method ;)